# Using lists to calculate grades Python 3, help simplifying code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

I need help/input on a homework assignment that I have. I already have a code that works but I was wondering if there was a simpler way to write the code to make it less lengthy.

Here are the directions for the assignment for reference:

There are ten names and five lists of test scores. The correspondence
between the names and the test scores are determined by positions. For example, the test scores for Cindy are 67, 92, 67, 43, 78. Drop the lowest of the five test scores for each student and average the rest and determine the letter grade for that student. Make sure your printout is the same as mine with the same column widths.

Here is my code:

```
names = ['April','Bill','Cindy','Dave','Emily',  'Frank','Gene','Hank','Irene','Jeff']
test1 = [34,21,67,45,88,  77,63,96,89,88]
test2 = [11,67,92,35,89,  25,78,94,81,63]
test3 = [94,33,67,34,67,  88,55,99,23,43]
test4 = [27,83,43,67,93,  45,67,77,86,90]
test5 = [43,76,78,45,65,  99,65,65,79,43]

total = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
min = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
percent = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
grade = ['F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F']

for i in range (10):
    total[i] = test1[i]
    min[i] = test1[i]
    
for i in range (10):
    total[i] = total[i] + test2[i]
    total[i] = total[i] + test3[i]
    total[i] = total[i] + test4[i]
    total[i] = total[i] + test5[i]
    min[i] = min[i] if min[i] < test2[i] else test2[i]
    min[i] = min[i] if min[i] < test3[i] else test3[i]
    min[i] = min[i] if min[i] < test4[i] else test4[i]
    min[i] = min[i] if min[i] < test5[i] else test5[i]
    total[i] = total[i] - min[i]
    
for i in range (10):
    percent[i] = total[i]/4.0
    if percent[i] >= 90: grade[i] = 'A'
    elif percent[i] >= 80: grade[i] = 'B'
    elif percent[i] >= 70: grade[i] = 'C'
    elif percent[i] >= 60: grade[i] = 'D'
    elif percent[i] >= 50: grade[i] = 'F'
    print (" %s\t%d %2.2f %s \n" %(names[i], total[i], percent[i], grade[i]))
```

The output should look like this:

```
April   198  49.50 F
Bill    259  64.75 D
Cindy   304  76.00 C
Dave    192  48.00 F
Emily   337  84.25 B
Frank   309  77.25 C
Gene    273  68.25 D
Hank    366  91.50 A
Irene   335  83.75 B
Jeff    284  71.00 C
```

Basically I just wanted to know if anyone had any ideas/methods for me to try in order to simplify the the code. I just get confused since the grades correspond vertically. It is good either way but I feel as if it could be modified. I am still somewhat a beginner, so I may not be familiar with what could be a simple fix :) Thanks!

Comment: [Have a look here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see if your question could be on-topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: @khelwood thanks. Should I repost it there? I haven't used Stack Overflow very much :)

Comment: If you think you can write a good question for codereview, go ahead, but make sure you read their [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page first. This question might be seen as too vague for Stack Overflow;

Answer (score 1):

This is an ideal use case for **dictionaries** rather than lists. Dictionaries allow you to assign values to keys. In this case, the keys would be the student names and the values their grades. E.g.,

```
{student_1 : [grade_1, grade_2 ... grade_n],
 ...
 student_n : [grade_1, grade_2 ... grade_n]
}
```

In this way it would be much easier to associate grades with any given student.

Also, some very **basic function definitions** (e.g. average grade) would be very helpful here. These prove to be super useful to create a clean output using an **f-string**.

In summary: looking up **dictionaries, functions and f-strings** could teach you a lot of useful skills for further coding. I have included an example below, hope it is somewhat understandable.

```
names = ['April','Bill','Cindy','Dave','Emily', 

'Frank','Gene','Hank','Irene','Jeff']

test1 = [34,21,67,45,88,  77,63,96,89,88]
test2 = [11,67,92,35,89,  25,78,94,81,63]
test3 = [94,33,67,34,67,  88,55,99,23,43]
test4 = [27,83,43,67,93,  45,67,77,86,90]
test5 = [43,76,78,45,65,  99,65,65,79,43]

#Assign every student to the dictionary
#So far their respective grades are an empty list
grades = dict()
for name in names:
    grades[name] = []

#Group all tests in a single list, which is easier to iterate over
tests = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5]

#Loop over all tests
#Every i-th student gets the i-th value of every test added to the dictionary
for test in tests:
    for i in range(len(test)):
        grades[names[i]].append(test[i])

#Remove the lowest grade and calculate the average afterwards
def avg_grade(grades):
    grades.remove(min(grades))
    return sum(grades) / len(grades)

#Associate a grade with a letter compared to a threshold
def letter(grade):
    thresholds = [90, 80, 70, 60, 50]
    letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F']
    for i in range(len(thresholds)):
        if grade >= thresholds[i]:
            return letters[i]

#Output as f-string
for name in names:
    print(f'{name:6} {avg_grade(grades[name]):.2f}  '
          f'{letter(avg_grade(grades[name]))}')
```